# ¿Como pasar valor de una variable a otro metodo (un modal) c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap

Tengo un gridview en un webform el cual tiene un asp:ButtonField para abrir una ventana modal y llenar un formulario, pero para ello necesito recuperar el valor del DataKeyNames, el caso, este es mi código pero al querer guardar los datos del formulario del modal mi variable idSolicitud es siempre null.
Este es mi codigo:

```html
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text='<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>' CommandName="Select1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="lightBlue" HeaderText="Editar" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

```html
protected void GridView1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "Select1")
{
index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
idSolicitud = Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ModalView", "<script>$(function() { $('#EditModal').modal('show'); });</script>", false);
}
}

//boton guardar del modal
protected void Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Estatus())
{
..
}
}

private bool Estatus()
{
idSolicitud = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["IdSolicitud"]);
con.Open();
string query = "insert into tbl (idSolicitud,..) values ("@IdSolicitud, ..)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdSolicitud", idSolicitud);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo un articulo relacionado

[[ASP.NET] PopUp Edición - Usando Jquery UI Dialog](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2012/06/aspnet-popup-edicion-usando-jquery-ui.html)

No necesitas de un evento en el servidor para tomar el id al presionar el link o boton, puedes hacer que este ejecute codigo directamente en el cliente.

En lugar de un `ButtonField` usa un `TemplatedField` para poder definir un link de html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asociarle un evento click de jquery

```
$("[id*='GridView1'] [id*='imgeditorder']").click(function () {

    var orderId = $(this).attr("idorder");

    $('#popuporderedit').data('orderId', orderId);
    $('#popuporderedit').dialog('open');

});
```

En este caso `imgeditorder` es el nombre de la imagen que actua como boton y tiene el id de la row que se selecciona, de alli se obtiene el id

Analiza el articulo para que veas como implementarlo

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero me marca error en idorder="<%#Eval("OrderID")%>"

Comment: que dice el error? recuerda que estas en un ItemTemplate y debes poner el nombre del campo que usaste en el DataKeyNames, o sea un campo que identifique la entidad

Comment: al hacer click en la imagen no hace nada

Comment: pero asociaste el click con jquery? , deberias ver que el selector este correcto